# Reflection in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am curious how this works. For example if I create a factory pattern based class where you can "register" classes for later use and then do something like

```
FactoryClass.register('YourClassName', [param, param, ...]);
FactoryClass.create('your_class_name').call_method_from_this_object
```

where `'class_name'` is a key in a hash that maps to value: `ClassName`

is there anything like [php reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), where I can create an instance of a class based on a string name and pass in the arguments in? (in php the arguments would be an array of them that php then knows how what to do with)

So if we take a real world example:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :something

  def initialize(input)
    @something = input
  end

  def get_something
    return @something
  end
end

# In the factory class, foo is then placed in a hash: {'foo' => 'Foo'}
# This step might not be required??
FactoryClass.create('Foo', ['hello'])

# Some where in your code:
FactoryClass.create('foo').get_something # => hello
```

Is this possible to do in ruby? I know everything is essentially an object, but I haven't seen any API or docs on creating class instances from string names like this and also passing in objects.

As for the hash above, thinking about it now I would probably have to do something like:

```
{'foo' => {'class' => 'Foo', 'params' => [param, param, ...]}}
```

This way when you call `.create` on the `FactoryClass` it would know, ok I can instantiate `Foo` with the associated params.

If I am way off base, please feel free to educate me.

Comment: are you referencing the idea of factories or the FactoryGirl gem that basically does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer that doesn't use `eval`.

PHP's `Reflection` is called `Metaprogramming` in Ruby, but they are quite different. Everything in Ruby is open and could be accessed.

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :something

  def initialize(input)
    @something = input
  end

  def get_something
    return @something
  end
end

@registered = { }
def register(reference_name, class_name, params=[])
  @registered[reference_name] = { class_name: class_name, params: [params].flatten }
end

def create(reference_name)
  h = @registered[reference_name]
  Object.const_get(h[:class_name]).new(*(h[:params]))
end

register('foo', 'Foo', ['something'])
puts create('foo').get_something
```

You can use `Object#const_get` to get objects from strings.    `Object.const_get('Foo')` will give you the object `Foo`.

However, you don't need to send class name as string. You can also pass around the class name as object and use that directly.

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :something

  def initialize(input)
    @something = input
  end

  def get_something
    return @something
  end
end

@registered = { }
def register(reference_name, class_name, params=[])
  @registered[reference_name] = { class_name: class_name, params: [params].flatten }
end

def create(reference_name)
  h = @registered[reference_name]
  h[:class_name].new(*(h[:params]))
end

register('foo', Foo, ['something else'])
puts create('foo').get_something
```

Comment: "Everything in Ruby is open and could be accessed." is a pretty far reaching blanket statement... is it true?

Answer (score 7):

Check out [`Module#const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) (retrieving a constant from a String) and [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-send) (calling a method from a String).

Answer (score 4):

Actually one of the strong points in ruby is meta-programming. So this is really easy to do in ruby.

I am going to skip the registering part, and jump straight to the creation
A simple implementation would be this

```
class FactoryClass 

  def self.create(class_name, params)
    klass = Object.const_get(class_name) 
    klass.new(*params)
  end

end
```

and then you can just do:

```
FactoryClass.create('YourClassName', [param, param, ...]);
```

and this would be equivalent to calling

```
YourClassName.new(param, param, ...)
```

Comment: the only issue with this is that the array of params is meant to be split up into `YourClassName.new(param, param)` if one of the params for the class was an array, you would store them as: `[param, param, [...]]`

Comment: Ok, that is a really small change: just use the splat operator: write `*params` to flatten the array. I edited it accordingly.