# Meta Programming and Unit Testing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, metaprogramming

I am using rspec to do my testing and while I am not looking for full blown answer, more of a pseudo code approach to get me going - I am unsure how to write tests for the following class.

```
module AisisWriter
  class ClassFactory
    class << self
      undef_method :new
      attr_accessor :registered_objects

      def register(class_name, klass, params = nil)
        if !params.is_a(Array)
          raise ArgumentError, "params must be an array"
        end

        registered_object[class_name] = {:class_name => klass, :params => !params.nil? ? params.flatten : nil}
      end

      def create(class_name, params = nil)
        if !params.is_a(Array)
          raise ArgumentError, "params must be an array"
        end

        klass = registered_object[class_name]

        if !params.nil
          klass[:class_name].new(params.flatten)
        else
          flass[:class_name].new(*klass[:params])
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I write this class in rails to allow me to register frequently used classes and be able to quickly create them on the fly. This concept comes from [my question on reflection in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192968/reflection-in-ruby).

What I am unsure of how to test is two things. One I have to make sure the class you register is actually registered. Two that if you try and create an instance of the class that its actually created.

I could write a `get_registered_objects` function to help with the first one and compare it to an existing object or traverse it looking for specific attributes.

But the second part, how do you test that a class was instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test `.register` in isolation, you would need a getter or maybe a `.registered?` method which would allow you to access the internals of your singleton class.

You could also test `.register` by registering and then creating a class:

```
describe AisisWriter::ClassFactory do
  describe '.create' do
    let(:klass) { Hash.new }
    before { AisisWriter::ClassFactory.register('Foo', ClassStub, []) }

    it "registers the class" do
      instance = AisisWriter::ClassFactory.create('Foo', [])
      expect(instance).to be_a  
    end
  end
end
```

Apart from that your code is littered with issues - you may want to read up on how class variables work - and what `attr_accessor` does when placed in class eval.

Also you could reduce the arity and complexity of register by using:

```
def register(klass, params = nil)
  class_name = klass.name
end
```

Ruby uses `?` at the end of interrogative methods `is_a?`, `nil?`.